# How to check url format through regex?

Tags: python, regex

My url is in the format of

**/en/33/details**

But the number 33 is dynamic and I have to check if the url has **/en/** part and **/details** part and some number in between.

I tried checking through

```
if url == r'^/en/(?d[0-9]+)/details':
```

But i checked through the django url regex syntax but it doesn't work. May I know where I am going wrong

Comment: Remove the '?d' from your regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `(?d)`-like regex construct in Python.

You need to use `r'/en/\d+/details'` with `re.match`.

```
if re.match(r'/en/\d+/details')
```

The `re.match` method anchors the search at the start of the string, so this will only find a match if

- `/en/` - there is `/en/` at the start of the string, followed with
- `\d+` -  1 or more digits,
- `/details` - a literal string `/details`.

If you need to also anchor the pattern at the end, append `$`:

```
if re.match(r'/en/\d+/details$')  
                             ^
```

Comment: @Yogi then perhaps you should accept the answer... :P.